# understanding list comprehension in haskell (missing tuple)

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I have the following list-comprehension in haskell

```
list = [(x,y)| x<-[1..2], y<-[x..3]]
```

as answer i would expect the following list:

```
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]
```

but i receive:

```
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(2,3)]
```

so my question is: What happened to (2,1)?
can anybody explain how this result comes about? I know it has to todo with the y<-[x..3], but i did not get how it works...
Thank you for any help!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because it should be like this:

```
λ> [(x,y)| x<-[1..2], y<-[1..3]]  -- notice [1..3] instead of [x..3]
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]
```

For your original code `[(x,y)| x<-[1..2], y<-[x..3]]`, the traversal will be
like this:

x is `1` in the first iteration, and y is traversed from `[1..3]` resulting in

```
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)
```

In the next iteration, x is `2` and y is traversed from `[2..3]` resulting in

```
(2,2),(2,3)
```

which gives you

```
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(2,3)]
```